# RecycleView Scrolling and identification of child objects

Tags: android, mobile, automation, ui-automation, robotium

I have a Recycleview in my App, where in it has multiple options. But i am unable to scroll down the recycle view using robotium. Does robotium support scrolling of recycle view. And also can we identify the child objects in Recycleview.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same and found out that this is a new Feature in the Robotium version 5.3.1 ([see Changelog](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Changelog)).

Unfortunately only the methods `solo.scrollUp`, `solo.scrollDown`, `solo.scrollToTop` and `solo.scrollToBottom` can be used with the `recyclerView`. 
Methods like `solo.scrollListToLine` (what i need) don't work with `recyclerView` at this moment. Maybe this will be implemented in the next release.